# Ionic + mongoose, mongoose.connect is not a function

Tags: mongodb, ionic-framework, mongoose

With this version of mongoose installed by npm :

> "mongoose": "^4.11.6"

In my Ionic app I have imported mongoose this way :

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
```

When I try to connect with :

```
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/my_database';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
```

I get this error :

> _WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_mongoose__.connect is not a function

When I look into the javascript console to see what the mongoose object look like I have an object that indeed has no connect function :

> {PromiseProvider: {…}, Types: {…}, Error: ƒ, Schema: ƒ, VirtualType: ƒ, …}

Any idea ?

Comment: where are you importing mongoose. as far as i know you need to create separate server. you can use nodejs , expressjs to create a server . here is link for more reference https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-hotel-booking-app-with-ionic-2-mongodb-node/

Comment: I have mongoDB up and running locally, I have a Ionic app running properly ans I added mongoose with $npm intall mongoose --save

Comment: listen refer to link to the above comment to understand more. you cannot call mongoose in ionic . you need to create server.

Comment: Alright!! I get it. Mongoose is the way Nodejs communicates with MongoDB, but it run only on server-side where MongoDB is set.. I was confused as Ionic uses nodejs, I expected that Mongoose could be set locally and communicate with the remote server where MondoDB is running.

Thank you!